# Как запустить и остановить setInterval()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно запустить и остановить `setInterval()` по клику на кнопку, желательно чтобы пока функция неактивна на кнопке была надпись **Старт** а когда активна функция тогда **Стоп**.

Первое я сделал, функция запускается в текстовое поле `#test` добавляет цифру один, после каждого вызова функции (для примера).

Как остановить функцию `setInterval()` по клику?

```js
function start_add() {
  var data = $("#test").val();
  $("#test").val(parseInt(data) + 1);
}

$("#refresh").click(function() {
  setInterval(start_add, 2000);
});
```

```css
#refresh {
  color: #FFED6D;
  font: 14px Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0084EE;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
#refresh:hover {
  background: #2F9AEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="refresh">Старт/стоп</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `setInterval()` возвращает ID только что созданного интервала для его последующего удаления. Для удаления функцию `clearInterval()`.

Соответственно что бы удалить интервал в данном случае используем глобальную переменную (что в целом плохо) и функцию `clearInterval()`

```js
var intervalId = 0;
function start_add() {
  var data = $("#test").val();
  $("#test").val(parseInt(data) + 1);
}

$("#refresh").click(function() {
  if(intervalId > 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      $(this).text('Старт');
      intervalId = 0;
  } else {
      intervalId = setInterval(start_add, 2000);
      $(this).text('Стоп');
  }
});
```

```css
#refresh {
  color: #FFED6D;
  font: 14px Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0084EE;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
#refresh:hover {
  background: #2F9AEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="refresh">Старт</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Присваиваете `setInterval` переменной, а потом ее обнуляете

```js
var process = false;
function start_add() {
  $('#refresh').html('стоп');
  var data = $("#test").val();
  $("#test").val(parseInt(data) + 1);
}

$("#refresh").click(function() {
    if (process) {
        clearInterval(process);
        $('#refresh').html('старт');
    } else {
      process = window.setInterval('start_add();', 500);
    }
});
```

```css
#refresh {
  color: #FFED6D;
  font: 14px Arial, Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: #0084EE;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  margin: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
#refresh:hover {
  background: #2F9AEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="refresh">Старт/стоп</div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="1">
```

Comment: Вы тестировали, прежде чем отправить?

Comment: ну да... вроде работает. Жму "Выполнить код" - счетчик бежит... Если не работает - готов стереть ответ ;)

Comment: счетчик то бежит, но надпись на кнопке смущает при этом

Comment: а, ну да... простите - верх с низом перепутал :) исправлено

Comment: @cyadvert В вашем коде `setInterval()` запускается и останавливается но опять не запускаєтся, но все равно спасибо за ответ.